# How do you get the path in a ReactJS HashRouter constructed URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have the following

```
class EntityProfile extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.location) // This doesn't work
        console.log(window.location.hash.split('/')[2], 'this is my id')
        return (
            <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    <span>hiiii</span>
                    <span>{this.props.location}</span>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

And they're all within a HashRouter, there is one route in specific that looks like so:

```
                    <Route path="/foo/:id">
                        <FooBar/>
                    </Route>
```

And I want to get the "id" from that. I read that you can use `this.props.location` that appears to be undefined, I could get it using `window.location.hash.split('/')[2]` but that seems a bit dodgy. My uri looks like so: `http://localhost:5000/#/foo/1`, so in this case I would like to get `1`. What am I doing wrong with he location value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (`history`, `location`, and `match`) are only passed to a rendered component via the [route render methods](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods).

> ### Route render methods
>
> The recommended method of rendering something with a `<Route>` is to use
> children elements, as shown above. There are, however, a few other
> methods you can use to render something with a `<Route>`. These are
> provided mostly for supporting apps that were built with earlier
> versions of the router before hooks were introduced.
>
> - `<Route component>`
> - `<Route render>`
> - `<Route children>` function

Rendering children components just isn't enough to get the route props.

```
<Route path="/foo/:id">
  <FooBar /> // <-- no route props
</Route>
```

## Solution

For the given path `path="/foo/:id"` the `id` param will *actually* be on the [match](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match) object.

> ### match
>
> A match object contains information about how a `<Route path>` matched
> the URL. match objects contain the following properties:
>
> - **params - (object) Key/value pairs parsed from the URL corresponding to the dynamic segments of the path**
> - isExact - (boolean) true if the entire URL was matched (no trailing characters)
> - path - (string) The path pattern used to match. Useful for building nested `<Route>`s
> - url - (string) The matched portion of the URL. Useful for building nested `<Link>`s

Here are several methods for accessing the `params` object.

1. Render via the `component` prop and access via `props.match.params.id`.

   ```
   <Route
     path="/foo/:id"
     component={FooBar}
   />
   ```
2. Render via the `render` prop and access via `props.match.params.id`.

   ```
   <Route
     path="/foo/:id"
     render={(props) => <FooBar {...props} />}
   />
   ```
3. If child is functional component use the [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) React hook.

   ```
   const { id } = useParams();
   ```
4. Decorate the component with the [withRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component and access via `props.match.params.id`.

   ```
   default export withRouter(FooBar);
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <Route path="/foo/:id">
     <FooBar /> // <-- decorated component will receive route props
   </Route>
   ```

Comment: This is such a thorough explanation. Really appreciate you going through all of this.